# Closed sets in Real Analysis.

Tags: real-analysis

I've stumbled up upon a question that is: Let $F$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $F$ and $F^c$ are closed in $\mathbb{R}$. What can we say about the set $F$?

Well I know that $\mathbb{R}$ is a set that's both open and closed at the same time, and I know that if $F$ were open and its complement were also open then we can say that that set $F$ is no other then $\mathbb{R}$. Anyone have any idea on what we can conclude about this set $F$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the complement of an open set is closed, and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes I understand that but we have F and F complementary both closed.

Comment: ... and since $F$ is closed, $F^c$ is ...

Comment: if F is closed then F complement is open but it says that F and its complement are both closed.

Comment: @Module $F$ is closed if and only if $F^c$ is ...?

Comment: @DanielFischer F is closed iff F complement is open.

Comment: @Module Right. So you know $F^c$ is closed (by assumption) and open (since $F$ is closed). How can you use that?

Comment: And then you also have that $F^c$ is closed. So what can we say about $(F^c)^c=?$?

Comment: @DanielFischer   So from the assumption of F complement closed and knowing that if F is closed then its complement is open then I can conclude that F complement is at the same time open and closed so I can say that F is either R or the empty set.

Comment: @Module Right! Because $\mathbb{R}$ is connected.